# Using Floor() and Ceil() on floats in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm working with currency in my script and need to incorporate penny rounding, but the [Floor()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Math.htm#Floor_Rounding_down) and [Ceil()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Math.htm#Ceil) functions round down/up to the nearest integer and thus dump the ".00" suffix.

Examples:

1. Ceil(3.14) = **4**, when the desired output is **3.15**
2. Floor(3.12) = **3**, when the desired output is **3.10**

How might I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `round()`, `floor()` and `ceil()` only accomplished a portion of the required functionality, I wrote a small function to accomplish the proper rounding.

```
pennyRound(val)
{
    ;Performs penny rounding on inputted float, and
    ;returns calculated amount.

    sub := SubStr(val, 0, 1)
    subMult := round((sub * 0.01), 2)

    if (subMult <= 0.02) {
        price := round((val - subMult), 2)
        return price
    }
    else if (subMult > 0.02 && subMult < 0.05) {
        price := round(round(val, 1) + 0.05, 2)
        ;price := round((val + subMult), 2)
        return price
    }
    else if (subMult > 0.05 && subMult < 0.07) {
        price := floor(val*10)/10
        price := round(price + 0.05, 2)
        return price
    }
    else if (subMult > 0.07) {

        price := ceil(val*10)/10
        price := round(price, 2)
        return price
    }
    else {
        return val
    }
}
```

Comment: PennyRound(x) { return  round(round(x*20)/20,2) }

Comment: @ahkcoder Throw it up as an answer if you want the rep.

Answer (score 3):

Demonstrates rounding to 1/100's precision:

```
round( n, 2 )
floor( n*100 ) / 100
ceil( n*100 ) / 100
```

Examples:

```
round( 3.1415, 2 )           ; returns 3.14
floor( 3.12   * 10  ) / 10   ; returns 3.100000
ceil(  3.1415 * 100 ) / 100  ; returns 3.150000
```

Comment: With an input of "3.14" the output does not round up to 3.15, and similarly, floor(3.12*100) / 100 does not round down to 3.10

Comment: An input of 3.14 will never round up to 3.15. However, you can use the ceiling function to make 3.1415 become 3.15. As for the floor example, if you want 1 digit precision, divide and multiply by 10. For 2 digits, use 100. For 3 digits, use 1000.

Comment: I've provided an answer with the desired functionality. The functions provided did not accomplish the proper rounding as needed in their entirety. If you come up with a more elegant solution than the one in my answer, I'll be happy to accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you are seeking is a rounding to the nearest 0.05 or 1/20. Hence multiply by 20 instead of 100. Ceiling, Floor, and Round functions are then

```
round(ceil(3.14*20)/20,2)   ; 3.15
round(floor(3.14*20)/20,2)  ; 3.10
round(round(3.14*20)/20,2)  ; 3.15

round(ceil(3.12*20)/20,2)   ; 3.15
round(floor(3.12*20)/20,2)  ; 3.10
round(round(3.12*20)/20,2)  ; 3.10
```